# Unit test that all invocations of a method pass a serializable argument

Tags: java, reflections

I use the Hazelcast library in my project.
It's executor service has [this method](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/5.2.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IExecutorService.html#executeOnAllMembers-java.lang.Runnable-):

```
void executeOnAllMembers(@Nonnull Runnable command);
```

This can fail at runtime if it is passed a command that does not implement Serializable.

I want to write a unit test that proves all callers of this method pass Serializable commands. I feel I should be able to do this using the [Reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections), but I can't figure it out.

For example, I can find all methods that invoke the method *executeOnAllMembers*:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("com.my.pet.project"))
        .setScanners(new MemberUsageScanner()));
Method executeOnAllMembers =
        IExecutorService.class.getDeclaredMethod("executeOnAllMembers", Runnable.class);
Collection<Member> allMethodsThatInvokeIExecutorServiceExecuteOnAllMembers = 
        reflections.getMemberUsage(executeOnAllMembers);
```

but I need the type of the argument (some implementation of Runnable that should also implement Serializable) that those methods pass into *executeOnAllMembers*.

Is this possible? If not, is there another way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

Yes you can use the default [reflection api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) available for Java, by looping into the list of all your implemented interfaces. You get this list by calling the method `getInterfaces()` from you **class** type.

**Person** implementing serialization:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Looping into the list of interfaces:

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person("John Doe");
        Arrays.stream(person.getClass().getInterfaces()).forEach(type -> {
            if(type.getTypeName().equals(Serializable.class.getTypeName())) {
                System.out.println("The type is of type Serializable interface");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The type is not of type Serializable interface");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't really what I'm looking for. I've updated my question with an example of what the Reflections library can do.

Comment: I don't know this library. Have you tried to explore de default Java Reflection API?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with the Reflections library. Instead, I've added an Aspect to assert that the task is Serializable.

```
@Aspect
public class IExecutorServiceAspect {

    @Pointcut("target(com.hazelcast.core.IExecutorService)")
    public void iExecutorServiceBeans() { }

    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.hazelcast.core.IExecutorService.*(..))")
    public void publicIExecutorServiceMethods() { }

    @Around("iExecutorServiceBeans() && publicIExecutorServiceMethods()")
    public Object assertTaskIsSafeToPassIntoTheHazelcastGrid(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
        if (args.length > 0) {
            // The first arg is either a Runnable or Callable. It should also be Serializable.
            assert args[0] instanceof Serializable : "Task must be Serializable " + args[0].getClass(); 
        }
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```